# (Scalable) graphics instead of text for design purposes

Tags: android

Some `TextView`s in my App serve a design purpose with a custom font:

```
app:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
```

If the user has configured another font however, these `TextView`s are affected and display the text in a different font than the one I've configured for this `TextView`. This leads to a broken design.

To fix this I was thinking of replacing the `TextView`s with `ImageView`s and show a (scalable) graphic with the text in my font. The image should be scalable in order to be independent of the pixel density of the device the app is running on.

Is this a sound approach? Has anybody done this and can provide some hints of how to archive this?

Comment: you can't just use a custom font for texviews?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But when the user has configured a different font on his phone this will supersede the custom font I've set for the `TextView`.

Comment: i used app:fontFamily and user configuration doesn't change custom font in the app. maybe you can test it in other phone see it's happen there. but user can change text size in the app that you can prevent it by set textSize to dp not sp

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use the solution below:

totalDIP_X and totalDIP_Y represent the total number of DIPs per inch on the phone.

For example, if you want 5cm x 5cm image on every phone.

5cm = 1.968 inches

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
totalDIP_X = metrics.xdpi;
totalDIP_Y = metrics.ydpi;

imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (aBitmap, (int)(1.968*totalDIP_X), (int)(1.968*totalDIP_Y), false));
```

Comment: That solution is not complete: How do I get the text and the font into the Bitmap? Anyway, I was thinking about simply providing a scalable graphic instead of generating a scaled Bitmap on the fly.

Comment: Come to think of it, I suppose the Text wouldn't look sharp when it comes from a scaled Bitmap...

Answer (score 0):

i did't understand your question. maybe this can help you. if you wanna set the size of textview without textSize, to make text fill the view. you can set `autoSizeTextType` property to `uniform` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

and if you wanna text size be independent of screen density you can just change dp to mm that is short for millimeter